# How do I make a Subquery in project in the aggregation - MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a question a little strange. I have a collection with Transactions and another with Movements of Cash. Each movement of cash has the transaction id. How do I bring in my transaction project a vector with all the movement of cash that exist with the transaction id?

I pass the models to understand the structure of the base.

Transaction MODEL

```
    origin: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    letter: { type: String, trim: true, default: '' },
    number: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    date: { type: Date },
    startDate: { type: Date },
    endDate: { type: Date },
    expirationDate: { type: Date },
    basePrice: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    totalPrice: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    type: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'transaction-type' },
    printed: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    tracking: [{ date: { type: String, trim: true }, state: { type: String, trim: true } }],
    creationUser: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'user' },
    creationDate: { type: Date },
    operationType: { type: String, trim: true },
    updateUser: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'user' },
    updateDate: { type: Date }
```

Movement-of-cash MODEL

```
date: { type: Date },
expirationDate: { type: Date },
observation: { type: String, trim: true },
type: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'payment-method' },
transaction: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'transaction' },
creationUser: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'user' },
creationDate: { type: Date },
operationType: { type: String, trim: true },
updateUser: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'user' },
updateDate: { type: Date }
```

My query in transactions

```
 db.getCollection('transactions').aggregate([{
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "taxes",
        "localField": "taxes.tax",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "taxDetails"
    }
}, {
    "$addFields": {
        "taxes": {
            "$map": {
                "input": "$taxes",
                "as": "t",
                "in": {
                    "$mergeObjects": ["$$t", {
                        "tax": {
                            "$arrayElemAt": [{
                                "$filter": {
                                    "input": "$taxDetails",
                                    "as": "td",
                                    "cond": {
                                        "$eq": ["$$td._id", "$$t.tax"]
                                    }
                                }
                            }, 0]
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "transaction-types",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "localField": "type",
        "as": "type"
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": {
        "path": "$type",
        "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
    }
}, {
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "employees",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "localField": "employeeClosing",
        "as": "employeeClosing"
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": {
        "path": "$employeeClosing",
        "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
    }
}, {
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "companies",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "localField": "company",
        "as": "company"
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": {
        "path": "$company",
        "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
    }
}, {
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "shipment-methods",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "localField": "shipmentMethod",
        "as": "shipmentMethod"
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": {
        "path": "$shipmentMethod",
        "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
    }
}, {
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "addresses",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "localField": "deliveryAddress",
        "as": "deliveryAddress"
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": {
        "path": "$deliveryAddress",
        "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
    }
}, {
    "$sort": {
        "endDate": 1
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "_id": 1,
        "startDate": 1,
        "endDate": 1,
        "origin": 1,
        "number": 1,
        "orderNumber": 1,
        "observation": 1,
        "totalPrice": 1,
        "balance": 1,
        "state": 1,
        "madein": 1,
        "operationType": 1,
        "taxes": 1,
        "CAE": 1,
        "type._id": 1,
        "type.allowEdit": 1,
        "type.name": 1,
        "type.level": 1,
        "type.transactionMovement": 1,
        "type.electronics": 1,
        "branchOrigin": 1,
        "deliveryAddress.name": 1,
        "deliveryAddress.number": 1,
        "deliveryAddress.floor": 1,
        "deliveryAddress.flat": 1,
        "deliveryAddress.city": 1,
        "deliveryAddress.state": 1,
        "deliveryAddress.observation": 1,
        "shipmentMethod.name": 1,
        "company._id": 1,
        "company.name": 1,
        "employeeClosing._id": 1,
        "employeeClosing.name": 1
    }
}, {
    "$match": {
        "$or": [{
            "$and": [{
                "$or": [{
                    "state": "Cerrado"
                }, {
                    "state": "Pendiente de pago"
                }]
            }, {
                "balance": {
                    "$gt": 0
                }
            }]
        }, {
            "state": "Pago Confirmado"
        }, {
            "state": "Entregado"
        }, {
            "state": "Enviado"
        }],
        "madein": "pedidos-web",
        "operationType": {
            "$ne": "D"
        },
        "type.transactionMovement": "Venta"
    }
}])
```

I want to make the transaction query add all the movement of cash that exist in a vector with a lookup of type: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'payment-method'}

Comment: why don't use populate?? your query is complex

Comment: I need to bring the relations of movement of cash note that in movement of cash I have the transaction id but in the transaction there is no movement of cash id